# Building Rally Apps Intro to 2.0 SDK

Tags: rally

We have had some success with the Rally WS API for Python.  We want to take the plunge into the 2.0 SDK, and have started viewing the videos provided by David Thomas.  We have some JavaScript background, but Node JS package management is new to us.  In the third video, it is recommended to use the Terminal app that extends the Dev Tools in Chrome.

The Terminal requires a URL and authentication to work apparently (it does not appear as a regular command line terminal out of the box as is shown in the video).  After some research via Google, it appears that on Windows a Node.js proxy is needed.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/devtools-terminal/

The trials of Hercules were nothing compared to the amount of effort apparently needed to get the "npm install -g devtools-terminal" to successfully work (multiple Microsoft development tools with patching and repatching KB fixes, that never result in a successful result).  However, we could get npm to install the Rally App Builder on Windows.

On Ubuntu Linux (hoping to avoid the Windows nightmare with devtools-terminal), the npm is unable to successfully install the Rally App Builder (the error "No compatible version found" results).  Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Any combination to suggest to be able to run through the video introduction?  Buy a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for all the hassles trying to get devtools-terminal working in the Windows environment. I spent some time trying to get devtools-terminal running on Windows 8 and found, as you did, that it's "non-trivial". There are build/configure dependencies used by the installer like Python, etc. that are difficult to configure properly on Windows. Even after installing them, I couldn't get the devtools-terminal install to work correctly.

While the devtools-terminal gives you a nice/convenient way to make calls to npm and the rally-app-builder from Chrome, it's not a pre-requisite for developing Rally Apps on Windows.

After installing Node.js ([native .msi installer for Windows x64](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.24/x64/node-v0.10.24-x64.msi)), I was able to start a Node.js command prompt:

[image: Node.js Command Prompt]

Install the rally-app-builder:

[image: npm install rally-app-builder]

From there, I was able to follow along with the [David Thomas' excellent Rally AppSDK2 video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3PQ-IsMxhG14aDViKxlPZASIrHatNkft), and build an example simple Rally grid app. Whenever the video does a command in the Chrome devtools-terminal, I used my Node.js terminal instead. Seems to work well, if not quite as fluid as the Chrome add-in.